# Adding EditText to custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I recently updated a custom view so I could potentially add an `EditText` to the center of my canvas (so to speak).

After adding my `onDraw` code to `dispatchDraw` my custom `LinearLayout` works in the same way as my previous custom view did.

Now, how can I add an `EditText` smack in the middle of the layout?

So far I am trying this:

```
EditText edit = new EditText(getContext());
edit.setText("My EditText");
edit.setTextSize((int)Math.ceil(thickness/2));
edit.setWidth((int)(diameter*0.07f));
edit.setX(centerX);
edit.setY(centerY);

addView(edit);
```

Forgive some of the variables, they are not too important but I'm trying to add the `EditText` using the X and Y coordinates.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE:

I have updated my `LinearLayout` constructor to inflate the `comment_edit.xml` file to see if I could get it to work this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` constructor extract is as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_edit, this, false);
EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_comment);
edit.setText("Add Comment");
edit.setX(112);
edit.setY(117);
addView(view);
```

I have also tried:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_edit, this, false);
EditText edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext_comment);
edit.setText("Add Comment");
view.setX(112);
view.setY(117);
addView(view);
```

The `EditText` still does not appear

Comment: Fixed the null pointer by adding android:orientation="vertical" to my XML - Oops! Still the EditText is not there?

Comment: Do you previously add other views to that `LinearLayout`? Don't be afraid to give more details.

Comment: No, just the one custom (extended) LinearLayout. All I see is my original custom view which happens to be a speedometer. No EditText (comment field) to be seen!

Answer (score 0):

In case the answer is not found yet. Every dynamically created view should have layout parameters (WRAP_CONTENT, FILL_PARENT, etc) that is why is not shown. For more information please edit your question accordingly.
An example might be:

```
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT));
```

EDIT:

Now your problem is that the edit text is not centered. Ok, I can give you an overview but I believe you must research from now on because there are a lot of things to do. First of all the LinearLayout is what it says, is a layout that it stacks the views vertically or horizontally. The position of the text shouldn't be given with the actual pixels of the screen but with some other specific layout parameters. Take Gravity for example, it aligns the inner view of a layout to the center, left, etc. Add gravity property of the LinearLayout.

I hope it helped

Comment: Thanks - I have updated my question. I took your advice but instead of programatically setting layout params I've infalted an xml file.

Comment: Thanks, maybe it would be best to use a ViewGroup and somehow position my stuff where I want it. You see I have a canvas which draws my speedometer and over the top (and in center) of that I want an EditText. Does that make sense?

Comment: you should have stated these things from the start. It's much trickier that I first thought and a totally different topic. Ok, here is a thought to get you started: make canvas as a View object through code, try a RelativeLayout which places the inner views accordingly to specific parameters. And place EditText and Canvas wherever you want

Comment: I extended a ViewGroup and in onMeasure placed my edittext in the center as need.